# Bootstrap does not render the same desgin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have dowloaded the Bootstrap `bootstrap-3.3.6-dist` and placed the 3 direcories `css, Fonts, and js` as well as the index.html file inside the same direcotry as in the Screen shoot but when placing the code of this template

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/

and run the code in the browser I am not getting the same design as in the link. Please see the Screen shoot underneath. I tried it with the `maxcdn` link and it worked.

How can I get the same design with the downloaded Bootstrap?

**boostrap code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
      </div>

    </div><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->


  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**

After adding the following;

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I am still not getting this design, it is not the same.

[image]

Comment: Try changing the paths to 
 `href="css/bootstrap.min.css"` &
`src="js/bootstrap.min.js"`

Comment: @RatHat: I did but I am still not getting the same. What else should I do to get the same design? Please take a look at the Screen shoot in the Edit part.

Comment: Ok you need to add the starter-template.css <link href="css/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet"> that will have the style for the padding and stuff it should work now.

Comment: I made this change but without seccuss :(. I had it as `<link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">` and I changed it as u proposed also `<link href="css/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Silly question.. do you have starter-template.css in your css folder? This is what's inside http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/starter-template.css so that should correct your body padding issue that's why I'm asking.

Comment: No I do not have it in the scc Folder. So do I have to implement it? I mean as css Stylesheet.

Comment: Yes either grab it from their site or create it yourself and throw it in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that the paths you specified in the HTML file (`../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`) are not existing.

You either need to update all your paths in the HTML file e.g. to:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Or you move your files accordingly (I would not recommend this)

Note: `..` means one directory above the one where your `index.html` file is

Comment: I have Change the paths but it still does not look the same!! Please see Screen shoot

Comment: You have to do this for all the paths (not just those two). A very easy way to get the complete site is to go to http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/ and download it (on firefox, press Ctrl+S)

Answer (score 0):

your css and js folders are in the same folder that contain index.html file. and you give some different path for calling css and js files so please replace

```
 <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and

```
<script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

Please download the all the scripts or use cdn

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="http://getbootstrap.com/favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/docs/assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
      </div>

    </div><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I actually do not want to use the maxcdn. link and want to include the downloaded files. Please can u  adapt ur answer to the included files. Since I  added the following `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` but I am still not getting the same design. Please take a look at my edit part.